# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Selenium Webdriver using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, attributeerror

I am trying to use click command in Selenium webdriver using python. But I am getting the below error. Can some one help me?

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sagnik/Desktop/pp.py", line 13, in <module>
    user.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

input("Anything after scanning QR code")

names = ["ABC", "DEF"]

for name in names:
   print(name)
   user = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{0}"]'.format(name))

   user.click()
```

I think I am missing something. please suggest me

Answer (score 3):

```
find_elements_by_xpath()
```

returns a list of results. Maybe you want `find_element_by_xpath` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use @DanielleM.'s solution if `user` is a list with only one element, otherwise do:

```
for i in user:
    i.click()
```

Instead of:

```
user.click()
```